# How to compile project without run exe file after done?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded this project https://www.assembla.com/code/zmod/subversion/nodes/3 but seems like there is virus in zMod.exe file in the Release folder. So I want to compile the project by myself, because maybe that virus is only located in zMod.exe and the source code is safe. But Visual C++ 2010 runs the compiled program after compilation, and I think it could damage my system if that virus is located in the source code too. How can I disable this function?
**UPD:** Thx guys! Virus was located only in zMod.exe but after i build source code its safe. So author is a very badass...

Comment: Running after compilation is not the default - the project may have some post-build steps defined, which you can remove from Project Properties. However, if you suspect malware, delete it and move on to something else - it's not worth the risk.

Comment: Make sure that you're building the project (Build => Build Solution) and not debugging it (F5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be mistaken. Pressing F5 is *not* compiling. That's *debugging* which requires compiling and therefore it includes compiling.

If you want to compile something, either press F6 or go to the menu and select "Build".

That said, building *may* involve additional custom commands called pre- or post-build events. Check those events if you suspect foul play. They can include any action you can think of. You can find those in the properties of your project.

Comment: *press F6 or go to the menu and select "Build"* Is F6 universally build project or something? As far as I know if you pick the "General Development Settings" CTRL+SHIFT+B is "Build Solution". So, as far as keyboard shortcuts go, your mileage may vary.

Comment: For dinosaurs (Visual C++ 6 settings) it is F7. Always has been, always will ;)